# Passing GrobidExtractor.properties to Tika in Java?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm trying to write a Java application that uses the JournalParser to extract authors, citations, etc. from journal articles.  The documentation for the GrobidJournalParser gives instructions for the command line app and for TikaServer.  I need to point to Grobid running somewhere other than localhost:8080.  I have a GrobidExtractor.properties file containing the correct URL on my classpath, but it doesn't seem to get found - I get an error because it's trying to access Grobid on localhost:8080.

```
   WARNING: Interceptor for {http://localhost:8080/processHeaderDocument}WebClient has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody, ContentType: multipart/form-data
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(WebClient.java:1220)
```

Is there some other way to tell Tika or the JournalParser where to find Grobid?  The Javadocs were not helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained in the documentation on using GROBID with Tika](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/GrobidJournalParser), if you want to configure Tika to use an alternate GROBID server you do so with a file named `org/apache/tika/parser/journal/GrobidExtractor.properties`

You have only called yours `GrobidExtractor.properties`, which is why it isn't being picked up. The full path is required

Assuming you're using Linux, using the Tika app, and with the GROBID properties in the current directory, you'd need to fix it with something like:

```
mkdir -p org/apache/tika/parser/journal
mv GrobidExtractor.properties org/apache/tika/parser/journal/
java -classpath .:tika-app-1.13.jar org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --metadata journal.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, the full pathname requirement wasn't clear from the documentation.